# Generate file path for created file so it can be downloaded

Tags: 7, files

I'm writing a module based on [this Jeff Geerling post](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/using-batch-api-build-huge-csv) that will allow the user to use a form to select some data, and then use the Batch API to generate a large .csv file with the desired data and download it from the browser. I have the form and batch processing working fine, but I can't figure out how to determine the path for the created file, as referenced in this code snippet:

```
/**
 * Interim download step for downloading CSV file.
 */
function MYMODULE_download_csv_file_interim($list_id) {
  global $base_url;

  if (empty($_SESSION['csv_download_filename']) || empty($_SESSION['csv_download_file'])) {
    return t('Please visit your list subscribers page to begin a list download.');
  }

  $list = node_load($list_id);

  // Redirect to the download file.
  $redirect = base_path() . 'path/to/download/csv/' . $list_id;
  drupal_add_js('setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = "' . $redirect . '"; }, 2000);', 'inline');

  $download_link = l(t('click here to download the file'), 'path/to/download/csv/' . $list_id);
  $output = '<p>' . t('Your subscriber list is now ready for download. The download should begin automatically. If it does not begin downloading within 5 seconds, please !download_link.', array('!download_link' => $download_link)) . '</p>';
  $output .= '<p>' . l(t("&#8592; Back to %list subscribers", array('%list' => $list->title)), 'node/' . $list_id . '/subscribers', array('html' => TRUE)) . '</p>';
  return $output;
}
```

At this point in the code, `$_SESSION['csv_download_file']` is `tmp/my_file.csv`. I've tried to figure how to make this a valid url for downloading the file, but can't. For instance, I've tried using [file_create_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7.x), but it just returns the same path.

What do I need to use to make this a valid URL to pass to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

`/tmp` is outside of webroot so apache (or whatever) can't serve files from there.

You have 2 options:

1. Move the file from /tmp to your public files directory. This will mean anyone will have access to it (if they know the url). [See `file_unmanaged_move()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_move/7.x).

Eg.

```
$source = '/tmp/my_file.csv';
$destination = 'public://csv/my_file.csv';
file_unmanaged_move($source, $destination);
```

2. Stream the file to the browser via php. This means only people who can access your php script can get access to the file.

Eg.

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=my_file.csv');
return readfile('/tmp/my_file.csv');
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem actually came in modifying this line:

```
$redirect = base_path() . 'path/to/download/csv/' . $list_id;
```

to point to another page instead of a file. I actually was already doing what Felix suggested above, and am using `readfile()` in this function:

```
function mymodule_download_csv_file() {
  // For added security, make sure the beginning of the path is the same as that
  // returned by file_directory_temp() (to prevent users from gaining access to
  // arbitrary files on the server).
  if (strpos($_SESSION['csv_download_file'], file_directory_temp()) !== 0) {
    return 'Access denied.';
  }

  // Add HTTP headers for CSV file download.
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv; utf-8');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $_SESSION['csv_download_filename'], TRUE);

  // Allow caching, otherwise IE users can't dl over SSL (see issue #294).
  drupal_add_http_header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=300; must-revalidate');

  // Read the file to the output buffer and exit.
  readfile($_SESSION['csv_download_file']);
  exit;
}
```

So the trick was simply to add a menu item for this function, and then change the line above to point to the defined URL for this function.